# Get Console Key in C# without halting the Console?

Tags: c#, input, keyboard, console

I am making a Virtual Machine and I just ran into a BIG problem. I need to get a scan code value of what ever key is pressed at runtime , WITHOUT halting the console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are using Console.ReadKey()?  I believe what you're looking for is [Console.KeyAvailable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.keyavailable.aspx)